# How do i insert record when row is not exist in database within one table

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to insert a new record and same time it check the record is exist or not.but the query fails to show the function please give me suggestions. when application runs it shows FAILURE ( the Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.)this message from java file.I want to display messages in application records inserted or record exist.

```
//java file
           public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                            private Context context;

                            public SignupActivity(Context context) {
                                this.context = context;
                            }

                            protected void onPreExecute() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                                String fullName = arg0[0];
                              //  String userName = arg0[1];
                                String passWord = arg0[1];
                                String phoneNumber = arg0[2];
                                String emailAddress = arg0[3];

                                String link;
                                String data;
                                BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                                String result;

                                try {
                                    data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
                                //    data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
                                    data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
                                    data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
                                    data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

link = "http://mydoamin.com/mangoair10/tryrr.php" + data;
                        URL url = new URL(link);
                                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                                    result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                                    return result;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                         @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                String jsonStr = result;
                                if (jsonStr != null) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                                        String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                                        if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                       // Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON Please data Fill all the records.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please LogIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //php file
                        <?php
                        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
                        {
                           echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
                        }

                        $fullName = $_GET['fullname'];
                        //$userName = $_GET['username'];
                        $passWord = $_GET['password'];
                        $phoneNumber = $_GET['phonenumber'];
                        $emailAddress = $_GET['emailaddress'];

         $sql = "INSERT INTO users10 (fullname,password,phone,email)
                        SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$fullName', '$passWord', '$phoneNumber','$emailAddress') AS tmp
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT name FROM users10 WHERE phone = '$phoneNumber' OR email='$emailAddress'
                        ) LIMIT 1 ";

                        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                        if($result == true)
                        {
                                            echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
                                        }else{
                                            echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
                        }
                        mysqli_close($con);
                        ?>
```

Comment: First check if the record exists or not; then, execute the insertion SQL statement. That is, you should divide your sql into two. By the way, you should refactor your code. It is prone to SQL injection atttacts.

Comment: `Echo` `$sql` check if it has syntax error or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ali already said you need to check for user existence an then go ahead and create it:

```
/* Connect to the DB using MySQLi class */
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');    

/* If an error code is reported... */
if($mysql->connect_errno)
{
  echo json_encode(array(
    'query_result' => 'ERROR'
  ));
}
/* Otherwise go ahead... */
else
{
  /* Prepare a select statement to check user existence */
  $selectStmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users10` WHERE `phone` = ? OR `email` = ?");

  /* Retrieve arguments */
  $fullName = $_GET['fullname'];
  //$userName = $_GET['username'];
  $passWord = $_GET['password'];
  $phoneNumber = $_GET['phonenumber'];
  $emailAddress = $_GET['emailaddress'];

  /* Binding parameters */
  $selectStmt->bind_param('ss', $phoneNumber, $emailAddress);

  /* Execute statement */
  if (!$selectStmt->execute()) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'query_result' => 'ERROR'
    ));
  }
  else
  {
    /* If the number of returned rows is 0 */
    if(0 === $selectStmt->get_result()->num_rows)
    {
      $insertStmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO `users10` (`fullname`, `password`, `phone`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $insertStmt->bind_param('ssss', $fullName, $passWord, $phoneNumber, $emailAddress);

      /* Try to insert the new user */
      if (!$insertStmt->execute()) {
        echo json_encode(array(
          'query_result' => 'FAILURE'
        ));
      }
      else
      {
        echo json_encode(array(
          'query_result' => 'SUCCESS'
        ));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'query_result' => 'FAILURE'
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The output type and format is the same as what you've reported in your question ;)

Comment: i tried the above php code but it goes to catch block not in the try case

Comment: In which method? `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Can you please provide the content of the `jsonStr` in such method?

Comment: when i run the app it shows catch block message i.e Please LogIn i want to show particular task messages

Comment: ok, try with the simpliest way, change `Toast.makeText(context, "Please LogIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to `Toast.makeText(context, jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and write here the message you're getting

Comment: its gives exception message and shows page link and all the values which i entered for registrations

Comment: I've seen now that you're giving here the real hostname/domain of your application and that it is not protected... This is BAD, very BAD.

Comment: BTW I've tested the php script by myself and seems to work correctly so the problem is related to the Java code. I'm not an expert java developer but to me the code seems conceptually right, so you need to give to me Excpetion stack information in order to be of any help.

Comment: ...and I will add that the java code was not the "core" question as it was the SQL part. So you better accept an answer (or not, this is to you) on this question and open a more targeted question on the Java/Android category with a specific title.

Comment: Ok, first we need to check if the "API" is working correctly, so try to simulate a real appa call to http://yourdomain.com/mangoair10/tryrr.php like http://yourdomain.com/mangoair10/tryrr.php?fullname=luigi&password=test&phonenumb‌​er=1234&emailaddress=test%40example.com

Comment: _ BTW I've tested the php script by myself and seems to work correctly so the problem is related to the Java code. I'm not an expert java developer but to me the code seems conceptually right, so you need to give to me Excpetion stack information in order to be of any help_

This is not the way SO is intended to be, or at least is not the way i intend it; so please, if you don't follow my suggestions and give me detail to help you going to the solution don't keep asking me for a ready to go solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '

this will update a given record when it is present, but insert a new one if not.

[on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)